# when viewing Linux LiveCD, laptop monitor blinking like an old television without channel

Tags: linux, laptop

Ive just bought a new laptop with Windows 7. I'm trying to install Linux because I need `Terminal`

I've tried viewing Linux LiveCD (`OpenSuse 11.2` and `Xubuntu 9.04`).

But when the LiveCD started, my laptop monitor keep blinking like an old television without channel. I not be able to see anything.

What is all of this? Is this related to monitor frequency? Can I just ignore this and install Linux withour looking at LiveCD?

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular ubuntu livedvd...you might need more driver support than opensuse or xubuntu are providing.  If that's the case, then you can customize the drivers on your live/install media to work once you isolate it down to a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to frequency. It's likely to be a driver issue. Try choosing a VGA or other 'safe' mode form the bootloader.

If all you want Linux for is a decent command line environment you might be able to live with [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).